# A Bug in WildFly8 when testing with Arquillian

Tags: jakarta-ee, integration-testing, wildfly, wildfly-8, jboss-arquillian

Unfortunately it is a bug in Wildfly 8.* https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFLY-3396 which has been fixed in 9 version.

Is there any workaround for Wildfly 8.2?

Comment: Why don't you fork Wildfly 8.2.0.Final and merge the PR? That does fix your issue. https://github.com/wildfly/wildfly/tree/8.2.0.Final & https://github.com/stuartwdouglas/wildfly/commit/e51c23394fe98e09b01088faaf32079683141384

Comment: I thought about the same. But I am starting this with a maven build at Jenkins. so I would have to replace wildfly in maven repo at jenkins with my modified wildfly. what is a bit...

Comment: Well, if you have your own Maven Repository, like Nexus, you can branch out this as 8.2.0-WFLY-3396 and push to it. Then configure Jenkins to fetch from the Nexus. I'm not sure you will get a workaround, but good luck :)

Comment: I tried to play with maven parameters like <forkMode>once</forkMode> in surefire configuration. It helps... but it works very unpredicatble, so it is hard to say whether it really helps. I don't think so.